# Is it possible to link to a wiki page from a "Hyperlink or Picture" field without using an absolute URL?

Tags: list, hyperlink, wiki

I'm documenting company applications in a wiki. For reuse, I'm putting them into a list, which is then inserted onto relevant wiki pages.

What I'd like to do is link to the application's wiki page from the list row. I've thought of two ways of doing this:

1. Create a hyperlink field and insert links into that field in wiki format (`[[Link]]`). The field requires URLs, though, so that doesn't work.
2. Create a dynamic table with a row for each item in the applications list, then populate the appropriate table column with a link to the item's wiki page somehow. I don't know if that's possible in SharePoint.

Is there a way to link to the pages without hard-coding their absolute URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Calculated Columns set to datatype=Number can output HTML. But only in **Views**

So you could build your own link with

```
="<a href='" & [MYURL] & "'>" & [MYLINK] & "<a>"
```

Note: you can't use an existing Hyperlink column in a Formula, because a Calculated Column can't expand complex Fields (for the same reason you can't use Created By/Modified By or a Multi Choice Column)

Comment: That looks like it uses URLs, too, though, right? I'm wondering if there's a way to link a list column to a wiki page without hard-coding in its .aspx URL ... like with the `[[wiki link]]` syntax.

Comment: No, this way you create your own HTML **not** managed by SharePoint, so you can use relative URLs