# Getting current URL in Sharepoint Online

Tags: online

I have a column with Link which has the hyperlink type. Is it possible to use something like [Current URL] to get the URL you are currently on? Just like you can use [Me] when filtering.

EDIT: Let me paint the scene: I have a list of school internships. Starting with Countries which is a standard Sharepoint list. When Clicking on the list item I get to the /DispForm.aspx page which is locked for changes. I want to be able to replace the DispForm.aspx with a page of my own choosing.

I have also tried to create a new DispForm.aspx (custDispForm.aspx). This allows me to customize the page in Sharepoint Online to some extend but the added problem with this is that this page is shared by all other List Items. Exp. When I add a Content Editor to the custoDispForm.aspx of The Netherlands List Item and add some text like "The Netherlands are ...." this shows up on each other List Item page exp. Belgium, Frence, etc...

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve.  As far as I know we don't have [Current URL].

Comment: No, this functionality does not exist, you'd have to script up something

Comment: JavaScript has ``document.location.href`` and SharePoint adds: ``_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath`` you can use in JavaScript, What is you objective? The Hyperlink columns only accepts valid URLs, If you need different (dynamic) URLs you can go for [Text columns and Calculated columns to built your link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154668/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-wiki-page-from-a-hyperlink-or-picture-field-withou/154675#154675)